# The join probability density function of X and Y is f(x,y)={2 for 0<x<y, 0<y<1 and 0 otherwise

Tags: probability

(a) Compute the marginal density functions of X and Y

I have:
fX(x)= integral from 0 to 1 of 2dy = 2
fY(y)= integral from 0 to y of 2dx = 2y
Can someone confirm this?

(b) Find P{3X>Y}

I know P{Y<3X}=FY(3x) and d/dx(FY(3x))=3fY(3x), but I'm not sure what else I need to do here.

(c) Determine if X and Y are independent

I know that X and Y are independent if f(x,y)=fX(x)fY(y)
So 2=/(2)(2y) so they are not independent?

Answer (score 1):

Just think of it pictorially : the density function is 2 on the "upper left triangle" of the unit square $[0,1]\times [0,1]$, and zero elsewhere. So to compute marginal density $f_X$, just fix $x\in [0,1]$ and integrate over $y$. You should get this
$$
f_X(x) = \int_x^1 2dy
$$
Can you try this for $f_Y$ as well?

Comment: would fY be the integral from 0 to 1 of 2dx?